# How to display the products in modal body

Tags: reactjs

I struck in the code that trying to display the products in modal body but not displaying. when i click on image it showing in console but not getting an idea how to display products in modal body. For to display in modal i used react-bootstrap. modal pop up is displaying when i click on image and it displaying header and footer. But in modal body i want to display the product details which i clicked. can any one help ..

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { Grid, Row, Col, Image, Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
   import AddToCartView from "./AddToCartView";
   // import ProductView from './ProductView';

   class ProductList extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   show : false
  }
 }

  handleShow = (item) => { 
  this.getProductDetails(item);
  this.setState({
  show : true
  })
 }

handleClose = () => {
 this.setState({
 show : false
 })
}

getProductDetails = (prod) => {
//  console.log(id,'clicked');
console.log(prod);
console.log(prod.title);
console.log(prod.id);
console.log(prod.price);

// let click = document.getElementsByTagName(Image.id);
// console.log(click);

//  const { viewProducts } = this.props
//  console.log(viewProducts);

//  viewProducts.map((prod,id) => {
//    console.log(prod.ptype);
//  })

}
// console.log(viewProducts,'viewProducts');
render(){
const { viewProducts } = this.props;
return (
<div className="list-container">
  <div className="mobile-list">
    <h3> Showing { viewProducts.length } mobiles </h3>
  </div>
  <Grid>
    <Row>
      {viewProducts.map((item, key) => (
        <Col xs={8} md={4} lg={4}  key={item.id}>
          <figure>
            <Image onClick={() => this.handleShow(item) } src={item.image} 
     thumbnail />
            <figcaption>{item.title}</figcaption>
            <figcaption>
              <label>Rs. </label>
              {item.price}
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <Button bsStyle="primary"  onClick={this.props.onChange}>
            <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart" />
            Add
          </Button>
          <hr />
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
  </Grid>
 <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={() => this.handleClose()}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Product Details</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    {/* <ProductView  displayProductView= { (item) => 
  this.props.displayProductDetails(item) }/> */}

  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleClose()}>Close</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
</div>
 );
 };
}
export default ProductList;
```

Comment: You have commented code in modal body so un-comment that. you are not displaying anything in modalbody. you need to add something in modal body to show

Answer (score 0):

You are aware the `ProductView` component is commented out within the Modal Body right?

Comment: but it is not displaying even though if i uncommented.

Comment: Follow Richard Zhangs advice, just put some plain text in it's place and see if that renders first, to narrow down your issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where you pass the `item` to `ProductView`. Most likely your `ProductView` is getting nothing to display. Maybe you could change `render` of `ProductView` to just render a 'Hello' to see if that is the case.